# @State property keeping initial value instead of updating

Tags: ios, binding, swiftui, state

From a settings page, I want to :

- Navigate to a child view
- Let the user input update some value in a textfield
- Save this value in the user defaults
- Navigate back to the settings
- If the user opens the child view again, pre-fill the textfield with the previously saved value

Given the following (simple) code :

```swift
// User defaults wrapper
class SettingsProvider: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SettingsProvider()

    var savedValue: String {
        get { UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userdefaultskey") ?? "Default value" }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "userdefaultskey")
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Open child", destination: ChildView())
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @ObservedObject var settingsProvider = SettingsProvider.shared
    @State var text: String = SettingsProvider.shared.savedValue

    var body: some View {
        Text("Value is \(settingsProvider.savedValue)")
        TextField("Enter value", text: $text).background(Color.gray)
        Button("Save value") {
            settingsProvider.savedValue = text
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having the following behaviour : [video](https://streamable.com/gjo08c)

Can somebody explain to me why the `TextField` contains `Default value` the second time I open it ?
Is it a bug in SwiftUI that I should report, or am I missing something ?

If I kill & re-open the app, the textfield will contain (as expected) `Other value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an `onAppear { text = SettingsProvider.shared.savedValue }` under the Button like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Text("Value is \(settingsProvider.savedValue)")
    TextField("Enter value", text: $text).background(Color.gray)
    Button("Save value") {
        settingsProvider.savedValue = text
    }
    .onAppear {
        text = SettingsProvider.shared.savedValue  // <= add this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  
I've also noted that adding `@ObservedObject var settingsProvider = SettingsProvider.shared` to `SettingsView` fixes the issue.

I guess my question is : are these workarounds for a SwiftUI bug, or is this the expected behaviour ?